# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError, even when I created an application password (Python)?

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I've been researching for days on Stack Overflow on how to send an email via Gmail using `smtplib`. I've finally got the gist of what I'm supposed to do, if I don't want to turn on "Less secure app access." I've switched to using two-step verification, and I created an application password for my python program to use.

Here is my code:

```py
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email_gmail(subject, message, destination):
    # First assemble the message
    msg = MIMEText(message, 'plain')
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    # Login and send the message
    port = 465
    my_mail = 'sample@gmail.com'
    my_password = 'thepasswordtouse'
    context = ssl.create_default_context() 
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', port, context=context) as server:
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(my_mail, my_password)
        server.sendmail(my_mail, destination, msg.as_string())


send_email_gmail('Test subject', 'This is the message', 'sallysample@gmail.com')
```

However, when I run the above code, I get a `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/programs/python/testing/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    send_email_gmail('Test subject', 'This is the message', 'sallysample@gmail.com')
  File "/home/user/programs/python/testing/test.py", line 17, in send_email_gmail
    server.login(my_mail, my_password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 743, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 732, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 655, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w10sm17413068qtk.90 - gsmtp')
```

I've tried placing `server.ehlo()` various places around the code, I've tried using SSL and not using SSL, I've tried using different code structure, I've tried creating and re-creating new application passwords, I've tried logging in using my normal account and username, I've tried using my user name and my email address for the username argument of `server.login()`, I've tried using spaces in the password and no spaces, all of it gives the same error message. Also, this code is running on the same device that I normally log in on, so it doesn't have to do with the fact that it's an unknown device.

Can anyone shed some light on why I can't log in to my Gmail account, and how to make it so that I can?

Comment: I've copied & pasted your code, generated application specific password and it works perfectly (without app specific password I'm getting same error)... Note, that generated password is shown with spaces, but the password should be without spaces.

Comment: @hradecek Interesting that it worked for you. And yes, I tried with spaces and without, too. I forgot to mention that in my question. I'll keep trying various things, and let you know how it goes...

Comment: @hradecek No luck so far. I'm going to try the CAPTCHA thing that https://support.google.com recommends for if I can't log in to my account using my own email client.

Comment: Since I was just doing something similar which worked, I can only echo that your code seems fine. I had started with the 'less secure third-party access' and then switched to 2FA, with an app password. Currently, my Google account settings show "2-Step Verification" to "On" and "App passwords" as "1 password".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the cause of the problem.

I discovered this answer when looking for the solution to another related problem I've been having where I can't sign in to my Gmail account using Thunderbird. After searching for a solution, I came across [this message](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1344530#answer-1452410), which says:

> I think I have finally come to the bottom of this issue.
> It is described here:
> https://support.google.com/mail/thread/127545584/i-have-created-a-supervised-account-and-i-m-want-to-add-it-to-my-mail-app-in-mac-but-its-offline?hl=en&msgid=128001398
>
> Basically, according to recommended answer, it boils down to the following sentence:
>
> "Thanks. AFAIK, Accounts managed by Family Link are not allowed to sign in via email clients. I was unable to get my test child account added to Thunderbird. "
>
> Since I have recently started using Family Link to limit screen time on my phone,
> it seems that it prevents me from accessing Google Mail on Thunderbird.

My Gmail account is also managed by Family Link, so in order access my Gmail account using a third-party email client (like Thunderbird or, as in this case, a Python program), I'll have to disable Family Link.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not having to import the SSL function and deleting the below line of code

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
```

Try this instead

```py
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)

    # Perform operations via server
    server.login(my_mail, my_password)
    server.sendmail(my_mail, destination, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

The link to the full code is here

[Code Link](https://github.com/capitalistlion/gmail_python_function)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, this code doesn't work. I think the problem has something to do with my Gmail account, rather than my Python code. I'll probably vote to close the question as not reproducible.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin do you mind posting your error code. If you completed the setup instructions on the repository link and it still provided an error I would appreciate you letting me know what it is.

Comment: I did everything but create the virtual environment, and the error is the same as stated in the question. Does it make a difference if run in a virtual environment?